# Csharp XmlNode select single node error

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I am trying to delete an element on a specific match between the value from a textbox and from my Xml file. This is my code and I am getting an error in:

`string x = xnode.SelectSingleNode("Url").InnerText.ToString();`

```
       XmlDocument favourites = new XmlDocument();
        favourites.Load("Favourites.xml");


        foreach (XmlNode xnode in favourites.SelectNodes("Favourite/MyFavourite/Url"))
        {

            string x = xnode.SelectSingleNode("Url").InnerText.ToString();
            if (x == Url)
            {
                // xnode.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newchild,oldChild);
                xnode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xnode);

            }
        }
```

this is my xml:

```
 "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Favourite>
   <MyFavourite>
    <name>Haider</name>
    <Url>http://www.yahoo.com</Url>
  </MyFavourite>
  <MyFavourite>
    <name>Haider</name>
    <Url>http://www.gmail.com</Url>
  </MyFavourite>
  <MyFavourite>
    <name>Haider</name>
    <Url>http://www.naji.com</Url>
  </MyFavourite>
  <MyFavourite>
    <name>Haider</name>
    <Url>http://www.yahoo.com</Url>
  </MyFavourite>
  <MyFavourite>
    <name>Haider</name>
    <Url>http://www.yahoo.com</Url>
  </MyFavourite>
  <MyFavourite>
    <name>Haider</name>
    <Url>http://www.yahoo.com</Url>
  </MyFavourite>
</Favourite>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The varialbe `xnode` points already to the *URL* element. Just skip the second xpath query:

```
string x = xnode.InnerText.ToString();
```

But this means that you have to update the remove part of your code since the xnode does not point to the *MyFavourite* element:

```
XmlNode favoriteNode = xnode.ParentNode;
favoriteNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(favoriteNode);
```

Comment: this is the right answer thank you. but if you may help me with the remove part it is going through the xml and when find a match it go to the remove method but nothing is deleted from the file